# Solve for $c$ given $\frac{18}{2c}=3.8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Will someone explain how to solve for $c$ when $$\frac{18}{2c} =3.8$$
The answer is $\frac{45}{19}$, I just don't understand how that works.

I have tried $3.8+18 \times 2$ that's my best one but that leaves me with out a denominator and just $c=43.6$

Comment: When posting question you should show what you've tried and where you get stuck. This allows people to tailor their answers to your particular background knowledge of mathematics as well as demonstrate to people that you aren't just wanting someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: If you have $x = y$ then you can apply the same operation on the left and the right of the equal sign and still get the equality, right? Like multiplying by some $a$ would yield $ax = ay$ or summing $b$ would yield $x+b=y+b$. In these problems, you have to find some of these "equality-preserving" transformations that eventually end up having your unknown all alone on one side of the equal sign. I personally start by moving the unknown from the denominator up (which would mean multiplying by $c$ on both sides), then get rid of coefficients (which would mean dividing by $3.8$ on both sides).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\frac{18}{2c}=3.8\Longleftrightarrow\frac{18}{2c}=\frac{38}{10}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Cross multiply:

---

$$18\cdot10=38\cdot2c\Longleftrightarrow180=76c\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$c=\frac{180}{76}\Longleftrightarrow c=\frac{45}{19}$$

Comment: How is there a 10 under 38 and how did you get 38 from 3.8? I guess by moving over the decimal point but why?

Comment: @W.Zlacki $ \dfrac{38}{10} = 3.8$. It would help if in your post you explained what you tried.

Comment: I understand 38 over 10 = 3.8 but how did the 10 get there.

Comment: Then you obviously don't understand. Try watching some YouTube videos/tutorials on solving simple equations.

Comment: Oh, sorta like an inverse function right or wrong?

Comment: @W.Zlacki Wrong. $\dfrac{38}{10} = 3.8$ so we can replace the $3.8$ in the equation by $\dfrac{38}{10}$. What 10 are you talking about, the one under the 38?

Comment: Yes, the one under the 38, originally the 3.8.

Answer (score 3):

If you multiply both sides by $2c$ the equation stays the same, because it's the same as multiplying both sides by 1. Then you'll get:
$$18 = 3.8 * 2c$$

Then, if you divide both sides by $3.8$ you'll end up with 
$$18/3.8 = 2c$$
And when you divide both sides by 2 you get $$18/(3.8*2)$$
After which we can say $$c= 45/19$$

Comment: I still don't get it!

Comment: Well, you know how you can multiply by one and you get the same thing? For example $a * 1 = a$? You're doing a similar thing with division. If you have $5*b = c$, then you can say $d* (5*b) = d (c)$. Does that make sense?

Comment: for all $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$

Comment: Yes, it makes sense.

Comment: You're multiplying each side by $2c $ in the first step,  $1/3.8$ in the second step, and $1/2$ in the third step. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: You're just being creative with the numbers you're dividing so that it works. The $d$ in my first example.